# How to make all cards same size and aligned in a row?

Tags: css, flexbox

How to make all cards same size and aligned in a row?
I tried to use different styling but cards looks messy. I don know what do i need to change in my .css code.
I want it to look aligned with page and other cards

```
.card {
width: 90%;
margin: 1rem;
padding-bottom: 1rem;

text-align: center;
border: solid 2px #fcad02;
border-radius: 10px;
box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.card:hover {
box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(217, 218, 182, 0.2);
}

.card a {
color: white;
font-size: 1.2rem;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #1c36fc;
padding: 0.5rem;
border-radius: 7px;
font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
}

 /*     Display two cards per row at 576px breakpoint */
@media (min-width: 576px) {
.cards-container {
 /*     Set the display for the outer container to flex */
display: flex;
display: inline-block;

 justify-content: space-around;
  }

.card {
/*  Set the flex-basis so that two cards are displayed in each row. */
flex-basis: calc(50% - 3rem);
}
}

/*  Display four cards across one row at 992px breakpoint */
@media (min-width: 992px) {
.card {
flex-basis: calc(25% - 3rem);
padding-bottom: 1.5rem;
}
}

.cardHeader {
text-align: center;
  }
```

[image]

Comment: This would be a better task for CSS Grid which can control both directions at the same time.

Comment: Try giving the cards the `flex: 1` size. This will all give them an equal size within the flexbox, the browser default is `flex: auto`

Answer (score -1):

This is because the first card's subtitle is too wide and takes 2 lines.
So you need to set card's subtitle width to fixed length (or max-width) and also take into consideration the possible height of the subtitle. For example if it can take up to 4 lines, you should reserve the space on all cards.

Comment: Too broad as an answer. and really nasty to find out the correct width. Thats why you should change the approach completely.